# Get rid of big head in window bar in Google Chrome

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome

I'm running Google Chrome on Windows 8.1 (not professional).  There is a big head in the top left of the window, that isn't present on other computers that I use Chrome on.  It allows logging into chrome with a user profile.  Is this a windows 8 specific feature, and how can I get rid of the big ugly head?  My windows 7 pro machine running the same chrome version (37) doesn't have it.

[image: Chrome Window]

Answer (score 1):

I worked it out.  In settings for users, I must have added my user profile when I installed chrome.  Deleting the user stops chrome displaying the head.